# Find and Replace in Visual Studio 2012 lacks memory

Tags: visual-studio-2012, replace

Whenever I launch the Find and Replace dialog in Visual Studio 2012, the dropdowns for find, replace lists a static list of values. It fails to keep track of the recent find strings. When I close the dialog or navigate to another page and launch the dialog, it is not displaying the last find entries in the combo.

So, I have to keep the complex search strings like Regex patterns (My fav: "^\s*$\n" to remove all blank lines) somewhere outside.

Is there a workaround for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My life made little easy when I close the find dialog before I navigate into another page or close the solution. It is preserving the last search content. However I am not sure if any corner cases I am missing.